# How to track order in local machine

Tags: magento2, orders, shipment-tracking

After product order is placed, I want to track the order in my local machine for development purpose. Is there any free extension is available for testing propose.

Comment: what courier service you are using?

Answer (score 0):

[Magento 2 Order Status & Shipping Tracking Extension](https://store.plumrocket.com/order-status-shipping-tracking-magento2-extension.html)

[MAGENTO 2 ORDER TRACKING AND SMS NOTIFICATION](https://www.weltpixel.com/magento-2-order-tracking.html)